# Show a custom picture before a youtube video starts

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to display an image in the "player" div, and then after the visitor clicks the button, replace it with a video (replace the div with an iFrame).  Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html {
text-align: center;
}

#player {
display: inline-block;
width: 640px;
height: 360px;
background: url(http://placehold.it/640x360) no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>
    <p><button onclick="playMe()">Play</button></p>

    <script>
    function playMe() {
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work.

It works when the "playMe" function is removed, but I'd need the video start after a button/div/link is clicked. I've tried to put the picture and the video into separate `div`s, picture on top of the video and than after the click hide the top div and start the video, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a variable scoping issue.

The function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady needs to be a global variable - as does the player variable.

I believe this example should work as a basis for what you want (there's a race condition if you click the button before the api has downloaded, but a full implementation would probably be app-specific so I'll leave that to the reader)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html {
text-align: center;
}

#player {
display: inline-block;
width: 640px;
height: 360px;
background: url(http://placehold.it/640x360) no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>
    <p><button onclick="playMe()">Play</button></p>

    <script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. called after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        // don't need anything here
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function playMe() {
        if (window.YT) {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                        height: '360',
                        width: '640',
                        videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
                        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```